# Python decorator early parsing breaks a forward declaration

Tags: python, decorator

I've got a few objects in a system they need to know who their next in line are. Each one has a do_process() function, that must return the next class when it's done.

```
class A():
    def do_process(self):
        # dosomestuff
        return B(self)

class B():
    def do_process(self):
        # dosomestuff
        return C(self)

class C():
    def do_process(self):
        # dosomestuff
        return A(self)

a = A()
b = a.do_process()
c = b.do_process()
a2 = c.do_process()
```

I then noticed that all my functions do the same thing when they return, and I should really write a decorator for that. I wanted to tidy up the last line in do_process to make it clear that it's going to return using a decorator for clarity, so that it reads like so:

```
@next_process(B) # tell the reader up front that the next object is a B thing
def do_process
   # do some stuff
   # next_process decorator returns an instance of B for us
```

In my implementation, the constructor takes a few args, but it's always the same args, because A,B,C are in my code overriding a base class. A classic Factory pattern problem. BUT, I immediately ran into trouble because the decorator starts parsing this in class A, while B is not yet declared. I'm rubbish at writing decorators too, so I wrote a Factory hopeing to replace B with the string "B" to let the factory supply the next object to the decorator at runtime. But this went sour, because I can only add class B to my factory once B has been completely declared. The decorator however is wanting to get a copy of B already, it actually calls my factory while still parsing A, so it's calling my factory before the factory or anyone actually knows about B (class A itself, is not even registered in the Factory at this point either).

```
class A()
   @next_decorate(next=factory("B"))  # <= blows up because the factory has not yet got a way to return class B
   def do_process(self)
      # do some stuff
```

I'm not interested in why this works in C++, I have already forgotten how to write macros and factories in C++. I'd like to know, should I just stick with my long-hand, keep the factory for maintainability and learn to write more complex decorators later. Or am I missing a more Pythonic solution for tight couplings like this?

Comment: Just define them in the opposite order?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This was my simple longhand solution, to do it this way. The classes are selenium page-objects, and I wanted to not get stuck creating referrential circles, hence factory pattern felt like a route to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really stop thinking in C++ terms. You almost never need to write a factory, usually, just a simple mapping will do. Write your decorator up-front that takes the string version as an argument, but uses the mapping internally.

```
def next_process(next_):
    def deco(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return MAP[next_](self)
        return wrapper
    return deco

class Process:
    def __init__(self, prev_process):
        self.prev_process = prev_process

class A(Process):
    @next_process('B')
    def do_process(self):
        # dosomestuff
        return B(self)

class B(Process):
    @next_process('C')
    def do_process(self):
        # dosomestuff
        return C(self)

class C(Process):
    @next_process('A')
    def do_process(self):
        # dosomestuff
        return A(self)

MAP = {'A': A, 'B':B, 'C':C}
```

Note, the same principle applies if you go ahead and create some `factory` class. Just use that factory internally. Or don't make it evaluate eagerly.

Comment: Thank you @juanpa . This does exactly what I was after, my explanation was either passable, or you are very good at the puzzles. Bonus marks for expanding on the base class I had omitted. Each class in my application is a Selenium page object, hence the way I wanted a decorator so one page leads to another.
`@next_process('A')
    def do_process(self):
        # dosomestuff
        return self   # <== return self here, don't try construct page here`
Note: The solution constructs the result object twice , I changed the line above to not do that. Still 99% on the money! Tx